# React Navigation - Conditional rendering screen based on Context value in Routes.js

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, conditional-rendering, react-context

i have a problem about conditional rendering in RNavigation,

let say i have 3 tab (Home, Upload, Profile).

I need to handle about the `Upload screen`, if the user already login or not,

actually I've created my own Context contain `isLoggedin`, but i don't know how to use it in `Routes.js`

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Home:{ screen:Home },
  Upload:{ screen:Upload }, // here i need to handle if user not logged in yet i want to use screen:PleaseLogin
  //Upload:this.context.User.isLoggedin ? {screen:Upload} : {screen:PleaseLogin}
  Profile:{ screen:Profile },
})
```

I thought this case is different with [Auth Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/auth-flow/) that used `createSwitchNavigator`

how can i achieve it?

Edit:

> I don't know how to add `this.context` in `Routes.js` because `Routes.js` is not a `react component`

Comment: Is it necessary to use context-api?. you can use AsyncStorage for this also.

Comment: @AnusKaleem i think yes, all content of my pages is depending on the login status, because my app is not force the user to login/register before seeking the content

Comment: that too can be managed through asyncstorage. Just set isloggedin key to true upon successful login attempt and access that key from anywhere within your app.
AsyncStorage is same as SharedPreferences in android

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Upload:{ screen:this.context.User.isLoggedin ? Upload : PleaseLogin  },
```

Comment: i don't know how to add `this.context` in `Routes.js` because `Routes.js` is not a react component

Comment: Sorry for late response, as mentioned by @Asad , you can set the `isLoggedin` as a global variable in a react `component` then you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you may add a global variable where **this.context.User.isLoggedin** is going to set

```
global.isLoggedin = this.context.User.isLoggedin;
```

**then**

```
Upload:{ global.isLoggedin ? Upload : PleaseLogin  },
```